# How to Upgrade Ruby 1.8.7 to 1.9.2 in Rubinius

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubinius

When I compile "ruby -v" command it returns,

```
rubinius 2.0.0dev (1.8.7 78652b58 yyyy-mm-dd JI) [x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2]
```

How should I upgrade ruby 1.8.7 to 1.9.2 ?
Should I remove rubinius ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of deleting rubinius, I just write the command:

```
rvm ruby-1.9.3
```

then it works.

Comment: That just uses MRI version 1.9.3. Try using a environment variable in the directory which you'll be calling rbx by running `export RBXOPT=-X19` either that or reinstall rbx making the default 1.9 `rvm reinstall rbx --1.9`

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the language mode flag like so:

```
rbx -X19 my_script.rb
```

And to be clear, the Rubinius team is focusing on 1.9 support, so it's best to run Rubinius in 1.9 mode anyway.